# Altering behaviour on back button pressed in browser to stay on the same site

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form inside view after submiting it by button POST `Edit` Action is invoked. I want this form to be submited or nothing to happen(stay on the same page) if user clicks back button in browser.

**Question:** Can I alter behaviour of back button for `Edit.cshtml` view to make it not working? I mean to stay on the same page?

Tried this in Razor view. No result, no popup window, nothing:

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        var message = 'All changes will get lost!';
        if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
            event = window.event;
        }
        if (event) {
            event.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Web development 101:  **NEVER** break the back button.

Comment: @briansol It is closed application for work, users will be forbidden to click back button but if they do I want to be sure nothng happens.

Comment: You cannot stop users from clicking the back button. Best you can do is trap the onbeforeunload event and beg them to stay.

Comment: @SalmanA Some persistent website trap user on them and make them stay on this website. Maybe this is possible to reload `Edit` view on back button clicked?

Comment: @Yoda, Why do you want this behavior? Maybe there's another way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

There's two events you can attach to: `beforeunload` or `unload`. As the name implies, `beforeunload` is fired before `unload` and allows a chance to cancel the unload with the user's permission. Your app cannot force the cancelling of the unload; a confirmation dialog will be presented to user, and only if they choose to click "Cancel", will it be cancelled.

So, to answer part of your question, no, you cannot force the user to stay on the page. If they want to go back, ultimately, they will be allowed to go back. The most you can do is politely request that they stay on the page. However, you can take the opportunity, through either of these events, to issue a *synchronous* AJAX request to do something like save the form state. The "synchronous" part is key. If you use traditional async AJAX, the browser won't wait around for the response and will unload the page before the AJAX can finish.

However, all of this is really for a different age. Now that there's things like local storage in HTML5, this is a far better method to handle saving state. Just add the user's inputs to local storage when they change a field, and when your form loads, attempt to read any values in local storage back into their corresponding fields. That way if the user goes back, goes to another page, or even leaves your site entirely, the form will still have their previously entered information when they come back.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on this subject. How to define what will happen(displaying window) onbeforeunload in razor view?

Comment: You can't really. If you return anything from the event handler, you just get a standard browser-specific confirmation window. You can return a string, which will be added to the confirmation window, but the standard text will still be there as well.

Comment: Yes, I want to get this confirmation window but it is not showing up. Tried also this: `<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        return 'Dialog text here.';
    };
</script>
`  browser does not care. IE and Chrome

Comment: I tried also that to be sure that I make no mistake: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onunload this also does not work, no alert shown.

Comment: FWIW, w3schools is awful; avoid it like the plague. Anyways, it doesn't get any simpler than this: http://jsfiddle.net/5xzfz5xn/. (Make sure you reload the result frame only; jsfiddle has it's own beforeunload for the main page).

Comment: The problem was that my script was not in section scripts. The problem now is that I get message when I also leave site by submit button only when somebody clicks back button.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you cannot disable the back button. Imagine what sleazy websites can do with this power. If you don't want to go the `beforeunload` route mentioned by Chris Pratt, another option is to open your form in a new page; this way, it will have nothing in its history to go back to, so the back button will be disabled.